# How to add credential column in authentication adepter using ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

My auth adapter is like below

```
 $authAdapter->setTableName('register')
                        ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                        ->setCredentialColumn('pwd');
```

It's working fine :

but now i want to check status column active/inactive also.

How can we add one more credential column here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `setCredentialTreatment()` method

```
$authAdapter->setTableName('register')
            ->setIdentityColumn('username')
            ->setCredentialColumn('pwd')
            ->setCredentialTreatment('? AND status = "active"');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where('status = "active"');
$authAdapter->authenticate();
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html), under the **Advanced Usage By Example** heading.